# iOS Left "More" UIBarButtonItem (in navigation controller) if UITabBar is hidden

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar, uibarbuttonitem

In my ios5 application I have a TabBar, and for each tab I have a navigation Controller.
I have more than 5 tabs, but if I set HIDDEN to YES to my tab bar a UIBarButtonItem with text "More" will appear in my navigation bar (leftItemsSupplementBackButton is set to YES) to the left - only in rootViewControllers, and there's no way to get reference to this button.
Pressing this button it will go to moreNavigationController.

Any ideas how to hide this button?

Comment: in viewDidAppear, [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems count] is telling me there's one button (mine) but there are 2 buttons: mine and  "More" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The More Button is the back button standard will appear automatically if one of the > 4 tab bar item is selected, even if tab bar is hidden. The workaround to get hidden this button is to hide, only if view controller is rootviewcontroller, the back button:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```